# Read selected entries from a text file in Python

Tags: python

Just for fun I am making a program where I can add all my account logins and passwords into a text file. It has four main tasks that can be run:

- Add an entry
- Change an entry
- View an entry
- Delete an entry

I know how to add an entry, but I don't know how to view a single entry from a text file.

The order in which it is in my text file is: Service, Username, Password

Here is my code:

```
def Add():
   service = input(str("What is the service?\n>")
   username = input(str("What is the username of this entry?\n")
   password = input(str("Please input the password of this entry")
   entry = str("\n" + service + "-" + username + "," + password)
   f = open("Logins.txt", "a")
   f.write(entry)
   f.close()
   check = input(str("Your entry has been saved\n"))
   time.sleep(3)
```

[An image of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yGRC.png)

Comment: Please post code directly in your question, instead of an outside image provider.

Comment: I edited this user's question and transcribed the code from the image into the question body itself

Comment: Are you sure it is a good idea to store passwords like this in a text file?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I'd change the text file to a better format, such as CSV. To do this, change the "-" delimiter to a comma. Also, use the python csv library to perform operations.

Then, add a new option to "display list" or something similar that calls a function like this:

```
def view():
    csvfile = open('Logins.txt', 'rb')
    row_num = 1
    csvFileArray = []
    print("Select a row number to view:\n")
    for row in csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',') 
        print(str(row_num) + ") " + row[0] + " " + row[1] ... + "\n")
        # insert all rows (lines) from the csv file into a python array
        csvFileArray.append(row)
        row_num += 1

    my_row_choice = input(str("Row number: \n")
    my_row_choice = int(my_row_choice)
    # since arrays are 0-indexed, take the number presented to the user and subtract 1
    # then, the rows are represented by array elements within each line, so we display like csvFileArray[my_row_num-1][0] for service, etc.
    print("Service: " + csvFileArray[my_row_choice-1][0] + " Username: " + csvFileArray[my_row_choice-1][1] + " Password: " + csvFileArray[my_row_num-1][2])
```

All you have to do is present the user with a list of options they can select, and call the appropriate function (e.g. "display list" which calls `view()`, etc.) based on their selection.

This is just off the top of my head, but it should get you started. There are other ways to pull out specific rows without having to loop through the whole file, but this should accomplish the basics of what you want.

More info the csv library can be found here:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Comment: Hey sir i understand all of what that code does, however the last line i cant quite wrap my head around because it keeps showing an error, I've been trying for about a day now to successfully debug it and find the problem but i just don't know where to start, Can you please expand on it?

Comment: What error is it showing? It may just be a formatting issue.

Comment: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'

Comment: The my_row_choice variable needs to be an integer - cast it back to an integer - int(my_row_choice)

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
def Add():
    service = input("What is the service?\n>")
    username = input("What is the username of this entry\n")
    Password = input("Please input the password of this entry")
    entry = f"{service}-{username},{Password}\n"
    with open("Logins.txt","a") as f:
        f.write(entry)

def entry(index):
    with open("Logins.txt","r") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        entries = [f for f in lines if f]
    return entries[index]

print(entry(0))
```